# how to build a 2D array using java by entering user-input?

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner, multidimensional-array

i have to build a 2D array that ask user to enter numbers to build the 2D array i know how to build this array using the for loop. But  here i want to use the user input.

so anyone can help me ??

after i tried to run this program it display this error :

```
enter the elementss for the Matrix
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test7.test7.fill(test7.java:29)
    at test7.test7.main(test7.java:41)
```

## this is my code:

```
package test7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test7 {

    private int row = 4;
    private int col = 4;
    private int[][] matrix;

    public test7(int trow, int tcol) {

        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
    }

    public test7(int trow, int tcol, int[][] m) {

        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
        this.matrix = m;
    }

    public int[][] fill(){

        System.out.println("enter the elementss for the Matrix");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] data = new int[0][0];
        for(int i = 0; i< matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0 ;j< matrix[i].length; j++){
                int x = in.nextInt();
            }

        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Question2 q2 = new Question2(3, 2);
        q2.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is in your Question2  class. can you post the code of this class too??

Comment: sorry i have changed the name of the package and the name of the class i edit my question..sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Need to do this**

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

    int[][] ma=new int[3][2];
    test7 q2 = new test7(3, 2,ma);
    q2.fill();
}
```

**Instead of this**

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

    Question2 q2 = new Question2(3, 2);
    q2.fill();
}
```

**Reason**

You are not initializing your matrix any where that is why getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

declare your int[][] data array with what size you want. try this:

`public test7(int trow, int tcol) {
        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
        this.matrix = new int[trow][tcol];
    }`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are declared `matrix` without initializing it :  `private int[][] matrix;`, So, it's `null` now, as the constructor sets only the value of row and col, try to initialize it using the other constructor:

```
     Question2 q2 = new Question2(3, 2, new int[3][2]);
```

or give it the value in the first constructor execution:

```
public Question2(int trow, int tcol) {

    this.row = trow;
    this.col = tcol;
    this.matrix = new int[trow][tcol];
}
```